# input - How to set value on input tag with type number in robot framework?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I want to set values into some input tags but always failed at input tag with type number.

The input form is like this:

```
<div class="f-col grow-2">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label-small">Alert ID</label>
            <input type="number" min="0" class="input-text " autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" name="alert_id" value="">
            <span class="msg-helper"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="f-col grow-4">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label-small">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text " autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" name="alert_title" value="">
        <span class="msg-helper"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code I used to input the number

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary


*** Variables ***
${FILTER_ID_LOC} =  name=alert_id
${FILTER_TITLE_LOC} =  name=alert_title


*** Keywords ***
user inputs on filter
    [Arguments]  ${title}  ${alert_id}
    Fill title  ${title}
    Fill id  ${alert_id}

Fill title
     [Arguments]  ${value}
     run keyword and continue on failure  input text  ${FILTER_TITLE_LOC}  ${value}

Fill id
    [Arguments]  ${value}
    run keyword and continue on failure  input text  ${FILTER_ID_LOC}  ${value}

*** Test Cases ***
Scenario: User inputs values on filter
    [Template]  user inputs on filter

    # title         # alr_id
    some_title      100
```

I used chrome webdriver and it didn't work. Robot Framework shows error message:

```
InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
(Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774
(7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
```

Would it require something more?
I only found `input text` in the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Input%20Text%20Into%20Alert).

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: The error states "Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated", which means literally that - there is another element that is taking the user's input, you have to look at the DOM and target it.

Comment: @Todor: Thanks for your feedback. I updated my question.
So my intention is to set values into some input tags but always failed at input tag with type number.

Comment: **you have to look at the DOM and target it**

Strangely if I switched the order of `Fill id` and `Fill title` inside keyword `user inputs on filter`, the script went well and no error produced.

Could you explain why did this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Todor is correct. The error is a common one and researching StackOverflow will provide you with a number of explanations for it.

In more practical and simpler terms, there is likely another element in front of your desired element or your element is not yet ready to take input because it requires activation through a user event. Most likely a focus or click.

So, often the recommendation is to do just that. `Click Element` before `Input Element` when encountering this issue for no apparent reason.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will give it a try.

Comment: I've added `click element` at `Fill id` keyword but it throws the same error.

Comment: Is this the complete error, or the section you think is relevant?

Comment: The error came only from input tag with type number. I added my whole script into the question. 

Strangely if I switched the order of `Fill id` and `Fill title` inside keyword `user inputs on filter`, the script went well and no error produced.

Perhaps this error `invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated` was due to robot framework set values too fast on input tag?

Comment: _your desired element or your element is not yet ready to take input because it requires activation through a user event. Most likely a focus or click._
--> Marking this as the correct answer. Finally found the root cause. The input tag was indeed not loaded yet when keyword `Fill id` executed by Robot Framework.